# `objc_autoreleasePoolPush()` and `objc_autoreleasePoolPop()` functions and `@autoreleasepool` blocks

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-runtime, nsautoreleasepool

I read somewhere that when we use `@autoreleasepool { }` blocks with ARC enabled, the compiler generates code to get the `objc_autoreleasePoolPush()` and `objc_autoreleasePoolPop()` functions called at the beginning and at the end of the block, respectively.

However, when I compile an Objective-C file with `@autoreleasepool` blocks, these two functions don't get called, even with `-fobjc-arc`. Instead, the compiler generates code to allocate a new `NSAutoreleasePool` object (with something equivalent to `[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]`) at the beginning and to drain the pool (with a `-drain` call) at the end of the block.

So, are the `objc_autoreleasePoolPush()` and `objc_autoreleasePoolPop()` functions really supposed to be called with ARC enabled? If yes, what compiler options are missing?

Comment: Whether ARC is enabled is not relevant. `@autoreleasepool { }` block is compiled to `objc_autoreleasePoolPush()` and `objc_autoreleasePoolPop()` regardless of ARC.

Comment: @newacct Yes, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`objc_autoreleasePoolPush()` and `objc_autoreleasePoolPop()` are really supposed to be called at the beginning and at the and of an `@autoreleasepool` block, respectively, from the code generated by the compiler, starting from OSX 10.7/ iOS 5.0. The missing compiler option is `-fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.7`.

And, by the way, ARC has nothing to do with all this, so that `@autoreleasepool` blocks make the compiler generate calls to those two functions even with ARC not enabled.

Answer (score 2):

What's your deployment target set to? It may need to be OSX 10.8/iOS 6 to get the newer way of doing things.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using XCode. I'm compiling it from the command line. So, do you know whether there is any `clang` option to set the target from the command line?

Comment: Try `-isysroot $PATH_TO_YOUR/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk` and `-mmacosx-version-min=10.8`  Also what level of optimization are you using?  The autoreleasepool work might be getting inlined.

Comment: @iluvcapra Thanks for answering. I'm not on my Mac right now, but I will try these options when I get home. However, the second answer solved my problem. `-fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.7` makes clang to generate code to call `objc_autoreleasePoolPush()` and `objc_autoreleasePoolPop()`.